# Is there a method for finding what number is needed to achieve an increment in an average

Tags: c#, average

I am working on a personal project, and I need to calculate what increase in numbers will bump the average to the next increment, I am able to do this long winded with if statements but wondered if there is already an algorithm or method for this.

Example

- 8 numbers averaging 750.7
- which numbers need increasing to get to 751

Comment: You can increase any number by 2.4(8 * 0.3) to get to a mean of 751.

Comment: Don't you just need to increase one number by (751 - 750.7) * 8

Comment: Seems more of a maths problem than a coding one.

Comment: Are you asking about a proportional increase to each number (i.e. proportional to its existing magnitude)? Either way, it seems more like a maths question.

Comment: You are going to run in to precision problems here(in general), though with this particular issue as stated with the number supplied it would be fine. That's to say, numeric types in .net only have finite precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a programming problem, maybe there are simpler Maths formulas, but the following works.

**If you want to increase each number by the same amount then:**

Multiply the average value you want to have by the number of elements

751 * 8 = 6008

Minus the sum of your existing elements and Divide by the number of elements

6008 - 6005.6 = 2.4

2.4 / 8 = 0.3

Each number needs to be increased by 0.3 to make your average 751.

**If you want to just increment 1 number to increase your average then:**

Multiply the average value you want to have by the number of elements

751 * 8 = 6008

minus all the existing numbers except the one you want to increase / last value.
This will leave you with the new last value you should use.